# How to get old UDID in my new upgraded app

Tags: objective-c, ios5, udid

I am using `UDID` to save and retrieve data from `remote DB`, now apple had `depreciated` the UDID.
Now how can I retrieve already saved data if I update my app with new version which developed using `iOS5.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not, unless you saved the `UDID` some where, like the `NSUserDefaults`.

Apple does not allow apps to use the `[UIDevice uniqueIdentifier]` method any more. If this is used in your code Apple will reject the app.

Comment: Thanks for your answer... but i haven't saved the UDID anywhere, that is the problem here.

Comment: Then there is noway to get the `UDID`. Apple has disallowed any app that use the `UDID` in any way. Apple have been saying that they would eventually disallow access to the `UDID` ever since iOS 5. You may try and appeal to the review board to allow you to submit a app which still uses the `UDID`, but there is only a slim chance that they will allow it.

Comment: I also wrote a article on why using `UDID` is bad and that deprecating the `UDID` is a good thing: [Deprecating uniqueIdentifier is a good thing.](http://triplesoftware.nl/2012/03/uniqueidentifier-deprecated-is-a-good-thing/)

Answer (score -1):

Look at this library 
https://github.com/ylechelle/OpenUDID

Now we haven't access to the udid, but this class generate a random id. I don't know if you want to manage your push notification but it makes it very well!

Comment: The problems lies in the fact that the user data is stored in a database where the user is identified by the `UDID`. If the apps update without the `UDID` all the users will lose there data. Since `OpenUDID` will generate a new unique id this might work for new user but never for the old.

Answer (score -1):

In this case, you can not retrieve the data from db! you did not use other unique data such as email or ...?

The "uniqueIdentifier" was a method to creating UDID string, I am not sure but I think you can solve your problem by regenerating the UDID, I mean you should find the algorithm of creating UDID :O

Comment: But since he did not save the UDID all the user will lose there data. He use the UDID to identify user (actually device and not users). Thus yes we will be able to create a new unique ID this will not solve his problem.